# Roslyn - Is a INamedTypeSymbol of a class or subclass of a given type

Tags: c#, roslyn

Using reflection, its pretty straightforward to determine whether an object is of a given class, using something like this:

```
(t == typeof(MyClass)) || (typeof(MyClass).IsAssignableFrom(t))
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do the same with Roslyn's code analysis APIs.  I'm working with a loop like this, that attempts to find all local variable declarations in a solution.

```
foreach (var decl in rootNode.DescendantNodes().OfType<LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax>())
                {
                    var symbolInfo = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(decl.Declaration.Type);
                    var typeInfo = symbolInfo.Symbol as INamedTypeSymbol;
                    if (typeInfo == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    // WHAT DO?

                }
```

I'm ultimately trying to build a list of all variables which are of a given type, or are of a subclass of a given type.  It's easy enough to see how I could compare the name of the variable type to the name of the known type I am looking for - but I also need to handle the subclass case.

Is there a robust way to do this with Roslyn?

Comment: If you want to handle generics, this becomes very complicated.

Answer (score 7):

Within the Roslyn IDE codebase, we use [this extension method](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Shared/Extensions/ITypeSymbolExtensions.cs,190b4ed0932458fd,references).  Note that you need be careful about whether you want to include just base types, or also interfaces.  Also, do you care about generic instantiation?

Comment: What assembly would we need to include to get this extension method?

Comment: The link  is broken. And I'm not sure the method is still in the same class now: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/e18704cc41c1fdb90f9bfda0b27cde6447adb583/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Utilities/TypeSymbolExtensions.cs
Can you please post an update?

Comment: It's too late, but here is a permalink to what I think @KevinPilch was pointing to:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/0c933d5b15cf01be78814cac04c6259da63be480/src/Workspaces/SharedUtilitiesAndExtensions/Compiler/Core/Extensions/ITypeSymbolExtensions.cs#L167

Answer (score 5):

You can [call](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/CSharpExtensions.cs,387) `compilation.ClassifyConversion(source, target)` and check whether the result's `Kind` is `ConversionKind.ImplicitReference`.

Comment: ConversionKind is internal.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Semantics/Conversions/Conversion.cs,426

Answer (score 4):

I have a helper laying around from some time ago that checked for this. I haven't been up to date with Roslyn lately so someone might have to verify that this is (still) a proper solution.

Basically, once you have the `INamedTypeSymbol` you can check its `BaseType` property for the base class and its `AllInterfaces` property for all the interfaces it implements. I don't recall by heart whether the latter works on a semantic or syntactic level (as in: does it give you the interfaces that that specific type in the hierarchy implements or all interfaces in total). The name suggests the latter.

```
public static bool ImplementsInterfaceOrBaseClass(this INamedTypeSymbol typeSymbol, Type typeToCheck)
{
    if (typeSymbol == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (typeSymbol.MetadataName == typeToCheck.Name)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (typeSymbol.BaseType.MetadataName == typeToCheck.Name)
    {
        return true;
    }

    foreach (var @interface in typeSymbol.AllInterfaces)
    {
        if (@interface.MetadataName == typeToCheck.Name)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure those `Name` checks will work - they aren't normally the fully qualified names.

Comment: Would a different property like `FullName` be more appropriate? I'm not very familiar with the intricacies of it. I had a look at the extension method you detail but that seems like a generic version usable for many different kinds of symbols and might be a bit overkill here.